# show selected Firebase-object elements in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, element

I've a complex FirebaseDB Datamodell with ListAdapters for selected object-elements to be shown in a ListView in Android. Data is already on firebase.

When adding the complete object I get an exception because relating Android-ListView-Elements are missing ... so I have to add only the required DB elements.

I tried out a lot, but with result that Strings are mismatching with the items-ArrayList.

Log-Message:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.connexibel.proficrmfree, PID: 2750
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.connexibel.proficrmfree.lists.AccountsList$2.onChildAdded(AccountsList.java:257)

Line 257 is the described line (I've deleted all my comment-lines for you).

Has anyone the correct idea to get the right format???

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO2fS.png)

```
Android ListView.class:

package com.connexibel.proficrmfree.lists;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.connexibel.proficrmfree.R;
import com.connexibel.proficrmfree.adapters.ListAdapterAccounts;
import com.connexibel.proficrmfree.datamodell.DatamodellAccounts;
import com.connexibel.proficrmfree.detailviews.AccountsDetail;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AccountsList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<DatamodellAccounts> items;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    private AdView adViewTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accounts_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference refAccounts = db.getReference("Accounts");
        refAccounts.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                DatamodellAccounts dm_accounts = dataSnapshot.getValue(DatamodellAccounts.class);
                dm_accounts.setAccount_id(dataSnapshot.getKey());
//this is the critical position!!! -->
                items.add(dm_accounts.getAccount_name1(), dm_accounts.getAccount_name2(), dm_accounts.getAccount_adress1(), dm_accounts.getAccount_zipcode(), dm_accounts.getAccount_city(), dm_accounts.getAccount_country(), dm_accounts.getAccount_internet());
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAccountsPortrait);
                arrayAdapter = new ListAdapterAccounts(getApplicationContext(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountsDetail.class);
                        i.putExtra("account_id", items.get(position).getAccount_id());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                DatamodellAccounts dm_accounts = dataSnapshot.getValue(DatamodellAccounts.class);
                dm_accounts.setAccount_id(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                items.add(dm_accounts);
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAccountsPortrait);
                arrayAdapter = new ListAdapterAccounts(getApplicationContext(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountsDetail.class);
                        i.putExtra("account_id", items.get(position).getAccount_id());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DatamodellAccounts dm_accounts = dataSnapshot.getValue(DatamodellAccounts.class);
                dm_accounts.setAccount_id(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                items.remove(dm_accounts);
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAccountsPortrait);
                arrayAdapter = new ListAdapterAccounts(getApplicationContext(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountsDetail.class);
                        i.putExtra("account_id", items.get(position).getAccount_id());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                DatamodellAccounts dm_accounts = dataSnapshot.getValue(DatamodellAccounts.class);
                dm_accounts.setAccount_id(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                //der bestehenden Liste neu erzeugte Objekte hinzufügen
                items.add(dm_accounts);
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAccountsPortrait);
                arrayAdapter = new ListAdapterAccounts(getApplicationContext(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountsDetail.class);
                        i.putExtra("account_id", items.get(position).getAccount_id());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("Daten", databaseError.toString());

            }
        });


        adViewTop = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewTop);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        adViewTop.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to ever initialise items, you probably want to do :

```
ArrayList<DatamodellAccounts> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: @GerdMarinelli hey no worry, you can accept the answer if it helped you or do you need anything else ?

Comment: sure, you too :)